# Calculating Fourier Transform but always get a type error

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, python-3.6

I have a function f(t) that represents a square wave with amplitude 1 and frequency 1 Hz and I was asked to write program that c**reates an array of N=1000 elements containing a thousand equally spaced samples from a single cycle** of the said square wave and to **calculate the array's Fourier transform**. So I have written this code but I always get an error. Can somebody help me fix this.

```
from math import trunc, linspace
from numpy.fft import rfft, irfft
from pylab import plot, show

def f(t):
      if trunc(2*t) % 2 == 0:
          return 1
      else:
          return -1
N = linspace(0,1,1000)
y = map(f,N)
c = rfft(y)
plot(y)
```

the error i get is:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'map'
```

Comment: You need to provide the full error...

Comment: What do you really want?

Comment: If this is your complete code, the error is `NameError: name 'linspace' is not defined`. Isn't it obvious what the problem is and how to fix it? (Add the line `from numpy import linspace` near the top.) Of course, when you fix that error another one pops up. Read the error messages and act on them. Is there something particular you do not understand?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to include linspace while typing my question here. The error that pops up is TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'map'

Comment: Now you get a different error. The function `linspace` is not in the `math` module, where you try to import it, but in the `numpy` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 errors in your code:

1. Import all relevant modules: `from numpy import linspace` is missing.
2. In Python 3.x, `map` returns an iterator instead of a list. You need to use `y = list(map(f,N))`.

The below code resolving these issues runs successfully:

```
from math import trunc
from numpy import linspace
from numpy.fft import rfft, irfft
from pylab import plot, show

def f(t):
    if trunc(2*t) % 2 == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1
N = linspace(0,1,1000)
y = list(map(f,N))
c = rfft(y)
```

For `y` as an array, you can use `y = np.array(list(map(f,N)))`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!